# jQuery Validate - allow special characters in addmethod value

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm working with jQuery Validate here and what I'm trying to achieve is to validate a textarea using `addMethod` and have run into a little snag. Here's what I'm using:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkValue", function(value, element) {
  return value == 'This is what gets validated!' 
});
```

That works fine on its own, but I want to allow the value to validate even if the user adds line breaks to the textarea being validated. So, this:

```text
This is what gets validated!
```

or this:

```text
This is

what gets

validated!
```

Would both be considered valid. I can force line breaks in the jQuery using `\n` but then the line breaks must exist in in the user input to validate. I'd like it to validate whether or not there are line breaks. By default it appears as though it must be one or the other.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: You can just remove the line breaks before you check the string for validity: `return value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") == 'This is what gets validated!';`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I gave it a try but it doesn't want to validate unless it's all on one line. Dang.

Comment: I thought that was your goal, given the string you're comparing to..?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't specific enough, my bad. I'm hoping that it could validate whether or not the user added line breaks when typing in the textarea.

Comment: Ok well now I'm even more confused, as that's what the code I showed you does.

Comment: Well, you'll be ticked at me now because it does work after all. Had a missing character in the main validate function. Argh.Thanks, Rory! I very much appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working. I added the comment above as an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you can use a regular expression to remove the line breaks from the value you want to test with, like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkValue", function(value, element) {
  return value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '') == 'This is what gets validated!';  
});
```